# vbscript function is not executing correctly

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create basic vbscript program that acts a to-do list. It will have features to add to-do item to an array, modify item, delete item, and generate items. I am having trouble getting the program to execute the insert to-do item correctly. it shows an error at my if statement for choice= "1"

Also, any other suggestions about my code would be much appreciated!

```
Option Explicit
dim choice
dim fn
dim fh    
dim num_items
dim new_item
Dim to_do_list_array, objSHL
to_do_list_array = Array()


fn = InputBox("enter text file to open: ", "open text file")
set fh =CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn,8,true)


Do
choice=InputBox("Administrator To-do List " & chr(13) &  "'1' - Insert new         
to-to item, " & chr(13) & "'2'- Modify existing to-do item, " & chr(13) &     
"'3'- Remove existing to-do item," & chr(13) & "'4' - Generate list of to-do 
items," & chr(13) & "'5' - quit", "Administrator To-do List") 

If choice= "" Then MsgBox "You must enter a numeric value.", 48, "Invalid         
Entry"    
If choice= "1" Then AddtoArray(CurrentArray)
If choice= "2" Then document.write("test")
If choice= "3" Then document.write("test")
If choice= "4" Then document.write("test")
If choice= "5" Then WScript.quit()
Loop 

Function AddtoArray(CurrentArray)
to_do_list_array = AddtoArray(to_do_list_array)
Dim Value
If IsArray(CurrentArray) Then
Do
Value = InputBox(Join(CurrentArray,vbLf),"Add to your array.")
ReDim Preserve CurrentArray(UBound(CurrentArray) + 1)
CurrentArray(UBound(CurrentArray)) = Value
Loop Until Value = ""
End If
AddtoArray = CurrentArray
End Function

fh.close
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, in this code

```
to_do_list_array = AddtoArray(to_do_list_array) 

fn = InputBox("enter text file to open: ", "open text file")
```

the first line is executed first, and what the `AddtoArray` function does is

```
Function AddtoArray(CurrentArray)
Dim Value
    If IsArray(CurrentArray) Then
        Do
            Value = InputBox(Join(CurrentArray,vbLf),"Add to your array.")
....
```

Probably that first line should not be where it is

Comment: thank you, i moved that line, and the program executes in order. However, now when i try to call the function choice = "1" insert, it does not execute correctly, it runs into an error

Comment: @matthewarnold, Without more information on what the error is, I will point to the fact that the first line in the function `AddtoArray` is a call to itself. Try to remove this line.